# "Go" button on the Finder window

Tags: finder

I am trying to remove the plug-in for Unsubscribe to avoid the message appearing every time I open my Mac.  To do so, I am supposed to click on the "Go" button in the Finder window.  Unfortunately, I can't see where is the "Go" button on the Finder window on an iMac OS X Version 10.7.5.

Comment: `Go` appears in the menu bar when Finder has focus, not in the Finder window.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: ⌘⇧+G or `Go` in the top menu. There is no "go button" in any Finder Window, and never has been.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely directing you to the Go menu in Finder. It looks like this.

[image: Go menu]
<sub>(source: [macosxtips.co.uk](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/go-menu-library.png))</sub>

Answer (score -3):

Command-shift-K

Lets you directly to "go", then pick your submenu

Comment: ⌘⇧+K will get you to the network section on the finder.